# Add project brief in Doxygen LateX output

Tags: latex, doxygen

How do I add the `PROJECT_BRIEF` that I defined in the Doxyfile to the LaTeX output? I want it to appear just bellow the project title.

I have tried using

`/ref{$projectname}`

and

`/ref{$projectbrief}`

as explained in the [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html), in the LATEX_HEADER section, but it just displays as ??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version (1.8.13) of doxygen this is not directly possible.

doxygen has the possibility to use a dedicated header, option `LATEX_HEADER` in the doxygen configuration file. By generating a default header (`doxygen -w latex <header> <footer> <stylesheet>`), modifying the `<header>` and using the modified `<header>` it is possible to accomplish the required functionality.

In the default  you will find the line:

```
{\Large Your title here}\\
```

replace this with e.g.:

```
{\Large {$projectname} \\[1ex]\large {$projectnumber} \\[1ex]\large {$projectbrief} }\\
```

The [1ex] gives some extra vertical spacing between project* items

Comment: Does exactly what I need, thankyou. What does [1ex] do?